# Getting second thumbnail from JSON feed instead of the first.

Tags: javascript, json, thumbnails, blogger

I'm using this script to show related posts on my blog because it allows CSS customization unlike the external widgets where you can override their CSS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxSearched = 500;
  var minimum = 5;
  var maximum = 5;
  var imageSize = 100;
  var roundImages = false;
  var relatedTitle = true;
  var labelInTitle = false;
  var relatedTitleText = "Related Posts";
  var defaultImage = "";
  var campaignTracking = false;
  var campaignSource = "";
  var campaignMedium = "";
  var campaignName = "";
  var insertBefore = $('.comments');
  var labels = [];
  var label;
  var alternateLabel;
  var minposts = minimum - 1;
  var postlabels = $(".post-labels a");
  if (postlabels.length === 1) {
    label = postlabels.text().trim()
  } else if (postlabels.length > 1) {
    $(postlabels).each(function() {
      labels.push($(this).text().trim())
    });
    label = labels[Math.floor(labels.length * Math.random())];
    var labelLocation = labels.indexOf(label);
    if (labelLocation === labels.length - 1) {
      alternateLabel = labels[labelLocation - 1]
    } else {
      alternateLabel = labels[labelLocation + 1]
    }
  }
  if (label !== undefined) {
    var title = $(".entry-title").text().trim();
    var labelCount = 0;
    var alternateLabelCount = 0;
    var matches = [];
    var url = $('link[rel="alternate"][title*="Atom"]').eq(0).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: {
        "max-results": maxSearched,
        alt: "json-in-script"
      },
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(e) {
        $.each(e.feed.entry, function(t, n) {
          if (e.feed.entry[t].category !== undefined) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry[t].category.length; i++) {
              r.push(e.feed.entry[t].category[i].term)
            }
            if ($.inArray(label, r) !== -1) {
              labelCount++
            }
            if ($.inArray(alternateLabel, r) !== -1) {
              alternateLabelCount++
            }
          }
        });
        if (labelCount <= minposts && alternateLabelCount >= minposts) {
          label = alternateLabel
        }
        $.each(e.feed.entry, function(t, n) {
          if (e.feed.entry[t].category !== undefined) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < e.feed.entry[t].category.length; i++) {
              r.push(e.feed.entry[t].category[i].term)
            }
            if ($.inArray(label, r) !== -1) {
              var s = e.feed.entry[t].title.$t.trim();
              if (s !== title) {
                var o;
                for (var u = 0; u < e.feed.entry[t].link.length; u++) {
                  if (e.feed.entry[t].link[u].rel === "alternate") {
                    o = e.feed.entry[t].link[u].href
                  }
                }
                var a;
                if (e.feed.entry[t].media$thumbnail !== undefined) {
                  a = e.feed.entry[t].media$thumbnail.url.split(/s72-c/).join("s" + imageSize + "-c")
                } else {
                  a = defaultImage
                }
                if (matches.length < maxSearched && campaignTracking === false) {
                  matches.push('<li><a href="' + o + '"><img src="' + a + '" alt="' + s + '" nopin="nopin"><div class="pp-home-title"><div class="pp-center"><div class="pp-center2"><div id="related-title">' + s + "</div></div></div></div></a></li>")
                } else if (matches.length < maxSearched && campaignTracking === true) {
                  matches.push('<li><a href="' + o + "?utm_source=" + campaignSource + "&utm_medium=" + campaignMedium + "&utm_campaign=" + campaignName + '"><img src="' + a + '" alt="' + s + '" nopin="nopin"><div class="pp-home-title"><div class="pp-center"><div class="pp-center2"><div id="related-title">' + s + "</div></div></div></div></a></li>")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        });
        if (matches.length >= minimum) {
          if (relatedTitle === true && labelInTitle === true) {
            insertBefore.before('<div><div class="related-posts"><h5>' + relatedTitleText + ' <span class="related-term">' + label + "</span></h5><ul></ul></div></div>")
          } else if (relatedTitle === true && labelInTitle === false) {
            insertBefore.before('<div class="related-posts"><h5>' + relatedTitleText + "</h5><ul></ul></div>")
          } else {
            insertBefore.before('<div class="related-posts"><ul></ul></div>')
          }
          matches.sort(function() {
            return .5 - Math.random()
          });
          for (var t = 0; t < maximum; t++) {
            $(".related-posts ul").append(matches[t])
          }
        }
        insertBefore.css("clear", "both");
        $(".related-posts ul li").css("max-width", imageSize);
        $(".related-posts ul li img").css("max-width:100%");
        if (roundImages === true) {
          $(".related-posts ul li img").css("border-radius", "50%")
        }
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Currently the script shows the first image on the post and I would very much like it if it could show the second image instead. I'm not well informed when it comes to JSON feed, but I tried to include the following and none of them worked:

```
e.feed.entry[t].media$thumbnail[1].url.split(/s72-c/).join("s" + imageSize + "-c") 

e.feed.entry[t].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url.split(/s72-c/).join("s" + imageSize + "-c") 

if (e.feed.entry[t].media$group.media$thumbnail !== undefined) {

var thumb = t['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'];
```

Is it possible to choose which thumbnail to show with JSON? And if it is how to do I do it with the script above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .media$group.media$thumbnail[0] may be try .media$group.media$thumbnail[1]